# Tab reference links

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook in excel with monthly tabs and links form tab to tab.  i.e. beginning balance in February pull from ending balance in January.  When I copy a tab, say March to Create April, the new Tab will still link back to the February tab instead of the previous tab which would be March.  So I go in to April and change all the links to March form February.  Is there a way to set up the link so when I create a new tab using the copy function that the links will just refer to the the appropriate tab?

Comment: Use one cell for storing the source worksheet name. Make all your references relative to it.

Comment: @Akina it's a good candidate answer.. you should put it as full answer for this one.. you may throw an example to illustrate it. ( :

Comment: I'm lazy... sorry. And the solution seems is not difficult, the author can do it self I think...

Answer (score 0):

In the April tab.. Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> > replace **February!** to **March!** > click <kbd>replace all</kbd>.

Not a beautiful copy paste solution. but if you don't rename your sheet and leave it as the original Sheet1 , Sheet2 .. 
Then the use of `=INDIRECT("Sheet"&(SHEET(A1)-1)&"!A1",TRUE)` will be the copy paste solution you are looking for.

Hope it helps..